# How do I convert an ATL/MFC CString to a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, atl, cstring

Given the encoding of the project is probably Unicode (but not for sure) what is the best way of converting ATL::CString to QString?

What I have thought of is this:

```
CString c(_T("SOME_TEXT"));
//...
std::basic_string<TCHAR> intermediate((LPCTSTR)c);
QString q;

#ifdef _UNICODE 
q = QString::fromStdWString(intermediate);
#else
q = QString::fromStdString(intermediate);
#endif
```

Do you think that it works? Any other ideas?

Comment: actually no because for some reason i cannot link. before trying to link it, i wanted to ask if i am on the correct way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate conversion to a `std::string`. The `CString` class can be treated as a simple C-style string; that is, an array of characters. All you have to do is cast it to an `LPCTSTR`.

And once you have that, you just need to create the `QString` object depending on whether the characters in your `CString` are of type `char` or `wchar_t`. For the former, you can use one of the [standard constructors for `QString`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#QString-8), and for the latter, you can use the [`fromWCharArray` function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#fromWCharArray).

Something like the following code (untested, I don't have Qt installed anymore):

```
CString c(_T("SOME_TEXT"));
QString q;

#ifdef _UNICODE 
q = QString::fromWCharArray((LPCTSTR)c, c.GetLength());
#else
q = QString((LPCTSTR)c);
#endif
```

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, you have to disable "Treat `wchar_t` as a built-in type` in your project's Properties to get the above code to link correctly in Visual Studio ([source](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4625-WCHAR-to-QString-giving-error-in-vs2005)).

For `_UNICODE`, I believe you could also use the [`fromUtf16` function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#fromUtf16):

```
CString c(_T("SOME TEXT"));
QString q = QString::fromUtf16(c.GetBuffer(), c.GetLength());
```

Comment: Thanks :) Any ideas on why QString::fromWCharArray does not link? Strangely, It is the only function that linker cannot find...

Comment: @Ali: Perhaps you're using an older version of Qt that doesn't include that function? While you were leaving that comment, I added another possible solution. You might try that instead.

Comment: No no, i found the reason. it is [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4625-WCHAR-to-QString-giving-error-in-vs2005)

Comment: @Ali: Fascinating, I never would have guessed that. Still not sure I understand why it's necessary. I guess the VS compiler treats `wchar_t` differently than Qt is expecting.

Comment: Yep, i think so. I guess wchar_t is some typedef and when it is built-in, linker looks for the function which takes built in type parameter rather than typedef type parameter. i believe that's why it does not link.